# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. in raspberry pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4

I am following the tutorial to install TensorFlow Lit for raspberry pi4 from tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python). When I am running the following command:

> curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

I got this message.

> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Can anyone help me with what does it mean and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Note the (.asc after the .gpg = .gpg.asc)

This is the **asc**ii version which is expected by `apt-key`.

Comment: Didn't work for me... Still the same error